# Transferring data with Foreign Key constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have four tables

Transaction(pay_id,pay_date,cust_name,cust_phone,cust_adrs,prod_name,amt,qty)
and its 3 normalised versions

```
1. customer(cust_id, cust_name, cust_phone, cust_add)
2. product(prod_id,prod_name)
```

(** cust_id and prod_id are primary keys and I have already transferred data from Transaction to cutomer and product. Primary keys are populated by using SEQUENCES.**)

```
3. payment(pay_id,pay_date,amt,qty,prod_id,cust_id)
```

Now, I want to transfer data from Transaction to payment but cust_id, prod_id are foreign keys in payment table. How to transfer data from transaction to payment without harming the constraints?

Comment: since cust_name and prod_name may be not unique you will get a problem...

Comment: i suggest you to learn the basic concepts of database normalization again, and then think on your question... you will get answer...

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle or SQL Server? Do you want to transfer the data from one DBMS to the other?

Comment: I am using sql developer 11g. I want to transfer data from one table to another with foreign key constraints being intact.

Answer (score 0):

Join Transaction with customer and product and insert into payment

```
INSERT payment(pay_date,amt,qty,prod_id,cust_id)
SELECT T.pay_date,T.amt,T.qty,P.prod_id,C.cust_id
FROM Transaction T
    JOIN customer C
       ON T.cust_name = C.cust_name
          AND T.cust_phone = C.cust_phone
          AND T.cust_adrs = C.cust_adrs
    JOIN product P
        ON C.prod_name = P.prod_name
```